# What is the clientID in /tokens/oauth api in vanilla forums api v2

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, vanilla-forums

I am attempting to retrieve the vanilla access token by using the API endpoint "/tokens/oauth" with the parameters clientID and oauthToken. I have created an OAuth app in the vanilla dashboard and I am passing the clientID and oauthToken obtained from the SSO login. However, I consistently receive a 404 error with the message "clientID not found."

Trying:

```
{
  "clientID": "string",
  "oauthAccessToken": "string"
}
```

Getting:

> 404
> The provided client ID did not match the client ID that was configured within Vanilla.